# Exclude elements through PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I would like to exclude some elements from DOM to extract a piece of text.

For example, with this code:

```
<div>foo <b>bar</b></div>
```

I would like to extract only the text "foo". Is there any way to do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Pleas add the code you have so far.

Comment: You very nearly have an answer in the question title... [SimpleXML Parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: The code of the element->innertext is:

```
<span class="icon icon-calendar"></span>                             <time datetime="2019-11-28 00:00:00">28 nov 2019</time>                                                              <span class="icon icon-place"></span> Torreón
```

I would like to extract the text "Torreón". This code is a div's content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

PHP has built in function [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Thank you! Solved with the strip_tags_content() created function.